# How to install a prebuild QtScrcpy

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Recently i want to install QtScrcpy because it has key mapping support, Its says already "prebuild" tho but there's no install.sh or whatever it is on the zip archive.

Building it by copying its git seems too complicated for me because its need aqt.

Comment: could you post the contents of the zip file?

Comment: nvm im using zorin os based on ubuntu focal and its seems qtscrcpy need a newer ubuntu version